# SWIG C# Exception with Vector of Objects

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, swig

I have a custom exception in C++ that takes a **std::vector** of **MyCustomClass** objects as a parameter.

I am using swig to translate my C++ project to C#. To handle exceptions across C++ and C#, there is some filler code that is required to be written:

```
%insert(runtime) %{
  // Code to handle throwing of C# CustomApplicationException from C/C++ code.
  // The equivalent delegate to the callback, CSharpExceptionCallback_t, is CustomExceptionDelegate
  // and the equivalent customExceptionCallback instance is customDelegate
  typedef void (SWIGSTDCALL* CSharpExceptionCallback_t)(const char *);
  CSharpExceptionCallback_t customExceptionCallback = NULL;

  extern "C" SWIGEXPORT
  void SWIGSTDCALL CustomExceptionRegisterCallback(CSharpExceptionCallback_t customCallback) {
    customExceptionCallback = customCallback;
  }

  // Note that SWIG detects any method calls named starting with
  // SWIG_CSharpSetPendingException for warning 845
  static void SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionCustom(const char *msg) {
    customExceptionCallback(msg);
  }
%}

%pragma(csharp) imclasscode=%{
  class CustomExceptionHelper {
    // C# delegate for the C/C++ customExceptionCallback
    public delegate void CustomExceptionDelegate(string message);
    static CustomExceptionDelegate customDelegate =
                                   new CustomExceptionDelegate(SetPendingCustomException);

    [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("$dllimport", EntryPoint="CustomExceptionRegisterCallback")]
    public static extern
           void CustomExceptionRegisterCallback(CustomExceptionDelegate customCallback);

    static void SetPendingCustomException(string message) {
      SWIGPendingException.Set(new CustomApplicationException(message));
    }

    static CustomExceptionHelper() {
      CustomExceptionRegisterCallback(customDelegate);
    }
  }
  static CustomExceptionHelper exceptionHelper = new CustomExceptionHelper();
%}
```

Along with the custom C# Exception:

```
// Custom C# Exception
class CustomApplicationException : global::System.ApplicationException {
  public CustomApplicationException(string message) 
    : base(message) {
  }
}
```

And the SWIG interface code:

```
%typemap(throws, canthrow=1) std::out_of_range {
  SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionCustom($1.what());
  return $null;
}

%inline %{
void oddsonly(int input) throw (std::out_of_range) {
  if (input%2 != 1)
    throw std::out_of_range("number is not odd");
}
%}
```

(from http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_exceptions)

This works for basic exceptions (the example takes a string as a parameter), however now that I am attempting to pass a vector of objects, I'm hitting a wall. I've tried to use marshalling, but I'm not clear on how that works, or if that's even what I should be attempting in this situation.

Has anyone done this, or something similar?